# What is the best way to parse localized numbers from .NET/Razor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, localization, numbers

I have a .NET app that allows a user to choose their own language & culture (date/number formatting).  Their culture setting is stored in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` (also  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, but that's a separate issue).

When I print out a var via Razor, it shows in localized format:

```
<span>@bignum</span> (renders as "123.456" or "123,456")
```

However, I also need to pass some .NET vars to Javascript:

```
var js_bignum = @bignum;
```

The problem is that Javascript in this case does not understand the localized versions of these numbers, so it fails since the above statement becomes:

```
var js_bignum = 123,456;
```

It may be because the user's browser's culture setting is different from the user's webapp's culture setting.  At any rate, it's a situation we need to be able to handle.

So what's the easiest way to handle this?  I can create my own Javascript `ConvertToStandardNumberFormat()` that takes a string value from .NET and returns a "standard" number format, but that seems like a bit of a hack.  Is there a way to force .NET/razor to render a non-localized format number?

```
var js_bignum = @price.ToUnlocalizedFormat();  (Is there something like this?)
```

I'm just trying to figure out what the best practices are for this type of situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you call methods from Razor expressions at all? Because this is what `number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` should do (modulo Razor syntax for importing the right namespaces etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `@price.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

**Edit**

I have to disagree with João answer and would consider it a Bad Idea™. I would not recommend re-inventing the wheel. If you would prefer a more comprehensive approach, then I would opt to include a dedicated C# JSON encoding library (I would recommend [JsonFx.NET](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx)).

The most simple approach, I would make an HtmlHelper extension. Something like:

```
public static class JsonExtensions {
     public static string ToJson(this HtmlHelper html) {
         return new JsonWriter().Write(t);
     }
}
```

Then use it in a view with:

```
@Html.ToJson(price)
```

This should handle primitive types as well as complex types.

After that I would probably refactor things and try to come up with a better injection pattern so that I'm not creating a new `JsonWriter` with each call to the helper.

But this will be much more flexible (and tested) than rolling your own serializer in the form of a static helper class...

Comment: Thanks! The "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" is what I was missing.  This is exactly what I wanted - a culture-agnostic javascript-friendly formatting feature.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated in another answer an easy solution would be to call `ToString` with the `InvariantCulture`, however this does not clearly convey your intent and may induce people to assume that `InvariantCulture` works for other data types.

If I were you I would wrap the formatting logic in a helper class, something like the following and call the helper methods where needed:

```
public static class JsLiteral
{
    public static string From(float number)
    {
        return From((double)number);
    }

    public static string From(double number)
    {
        return number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static string From(bool flag)
    {
        return flag ? "true" : "false";
    }
}
```

This is easier to maintain and also clearly express your intents when you use it in a view `@JsLiteral.From(bignum)`.